# Table has no rows - Google Pie Chart using PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I am getting "Table has no columns" error. Please see the below link.

http://admin.millionkidstoschool.org/index.php/

What can be causing this problem?

On the provided link you can see the JSON Output under XHR.

Is it possible to draw multiple charts (pie, bar) using the same JSON output but a different set of data?

View:

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(filter_data); 


       function filter_data(){
           $('#filter_data').html("<div id='loading'></div>");
           var action = 'fetch_data';
           //var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
           //var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
           var reporting_period = get_filter('reporting_period');
           var category = get_filter('category');
           var region = get_filter('region');
           var partner = get_filter('partner');

           var mapData = $.ajax({
               url:"http://admin.millionkidstoschool.org/index.php/enrollments/fetch_data",
               type:"POST",
               dataType:"JSON",
               data:{action:action, reporting_period:reporting_period, category:category, region:region, partner:partner},

                /*success:function(data){
                   $('.filter_data').html(data.enrollments);
                   /*$('#pagination_link').html(data.pagination_link);
               }*/
           }).responseText;


           // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server. 
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(mapData);




            // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options. 
            var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('filter_data')); 
            chart.draw(data, {width: 900, height: 500}); 

       }
```

Controller:

```
        $data = $this->db->query($query);



        $result = '';
        $total_ex_nf = '0';
        $total_new_nf = '0';
        $total_formal='0';
        if($data->num_rows() > 0)
        {
            foreach($data->result_array() as $row)
            {
                if($row['category']=='Ex-Non-Formal'){
                    $total_ex_nf += $row['total_enrolled'];
                    //$result .= $total_ex_nf;
                }
                if($row['category']=='New-Non-Formal'){
                    $total_new_nf += $row['total_enrolled'];
                    //$result .= $total_new_nf;
                }
                if($row['category']=='Formal'){
                    $total_formal += $row['total_enrolled'];
                    //$result .= $total_formal;
                }

                $result .= '


                <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <div style="border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:5px; padding:16px; margin-bottom:16px;">


                  <p>Total Enrollments : '. $row['total_enrolled'].' <br />
                  Partner : '. $row['partner'] .'  <br />
                  Reporting Period : '. $row['reporting_period'] .' <br />
                  Category : '. $row['category'] .'<br />


                  Region : '. $row['region'] .'</p>
                 </div>
                </div>
                ';
            }

            $result .= '<div class="col-lg-12">

            Total Formal: '.$total_ex_nf.' <br/>
            Total Ex-Non-Formal: '.$total_new_nf.' <br/>
            Total New-Non-Formal: '.$total_formal.' <br/>

            </div>';


            $output = array('enrollments' => $result);
        }
        else
        {
            $result = '<h3>No Data Found</h3>';
        }

    $categoryType1 = "Fromal";
    $categoryType2 = "Ex-Non-Fromal";
    $categoryType3 = "New-Non-Fromal";

   $responce->cols[] = array( 
        "id" => "", 
        "label" => "Category", 
        "pattern" => "", 
        "type" => "string" 
    ); 
    $responce->cols[] = array( 
        "id" => "", 
        "label" => "Total Enrolled", 
        "pattern" => "", 
        "type" => "number" 
    ); 

        $responce->rows[0]["c"] = array( 
            array( 
                "v" => "$categoryType1", 
                "f" => null 
            ) , 
            array( 
                "v" => (int)$total_formal, 
                "f" => null 
            )
        ); 

        $responce->rows[1]["c"] = array( 
            array( 
                "v" => "$categoryType2", 
                "f" => null 
            ) , 
            array( 
                "v" => (int)$total_ex_nf, 
                "f" => null 
            )
        ); 

        $responce->rows[2]["c"] = array( 
            array(
                "v" => "$categoryType3", 
                "f" => null 
            ) , 
            array( 
                "v" => (int)$total_new_nf, 
                "f" => null 
            )
        ); 

    echo json_encode($responce);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jquery ajax function has a `.done()` function that gets triggered when the request is finished and get passed the data. Your way of accessing the data results in you passing the google charts a `jqXHR` object. For more information look here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

You can try something like this:

```
 google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(filter_data); 


       function filter_data(){
           $('#filter_data').html("<div id='loading'></div>");
           var action = 'fetch_data';
           //var minimum_price = $('#hidden_minimum_price').val();
           //var maximum_price = $('#hidden_maximum_price').val();
           var reporting_period = get_filter('reporting_period');
           var category = get_filter('category');
           var region = get_filter('region');
           var partner = get_filter('partner');

           var mapData = $.ajax({
               url:"http://admin.millionkidstoschool.org/index.php/enrollments/fetch_data",
               type:"POST",
               dataType:"JSON",
               data:{action:action, reporting_period:reporting_period, category:category, region:region, partner:partner},

                /*success:function(data){
                   $('.filter_data').html(data.enrollments);
                   /*$('#pagination_link').html(data.pagination_link);
               }*/
           }).done(function (mapData) {
               // Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server. 
               var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(mapData);

               // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options. 
              var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('filter_data')); 
              chart.draw(data, {width: 900, height: 500}); 
           });

       }
```

(This code is not tested, it should you give a hint in the right direction)

Comment: What is the result of console.log(mapData) inside the done function?